# Create SQL Job that runs for different databases in the same server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2`. I have different `five databases on the same server.` The `tables and stored procedure schema of all of them are the same` but the `data are different` as I have pointed them to different sites. Now, I want to create an `sql job` that runs at 9:30 pm everyday. And get data from database tables and store it to a temporary table. And one more sql job that writes the temporary table's data to LOG file.

I have created `two different stored procedures` for this -One fetches data and other writes it, and both are working OK for each database.

But the issue is, In sql server agent I don't want to create 2 SQL jobs for each database that gets the store procedure name and execute it (Total 10 sql jobs). Instead of that, I want to create `ONLY TWO SQL JOBS`. One will execute the stored procedure to fetch data into temporary tables and the other will be executed after the first completed and write data into log files for each database's saperate directory in the server.

As, I have the same stored procedure names and table names in the all five databases, is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried stacking the sprocs? That is create one sproc that calls all of the other ones? Such as `EXEC sproc1; EXEC sproc2;`

Comment: You mean to say I have to create one more stored procedure that calls all of stored procedures of different databases?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm not sure that's the only solution, however I have used it in the past.

Comment: OK, instead of creating a stored procedure, I would preffer to store these commands in a local directory text or sql file. And in the job, I would like to read the commands from that files and execute it. In that case, the problem of adding more databases in the same will also be solved by just appending more two script names in the same file. :) Is it possible?

Comment: You can do this code side, however I don't think it's possible to execute SQL commands pulled from a file server side, AFAIK at least. I solved this problem a few months ago by storing SQL commands as NVARCHAR in the DB then look them all up and execute them in order code side. I couldn't find a solution to keep them all within SQL though you might be able to combine a look up + cursor loop + EXEC to manage it.

Comment: Hey !! Thanks. It has worked !!! :) I just created an sql file in which I passed EXEC command along with databasename.dbo.stored procedure name. And opened it in step, I have executed it for 3 databases and it worked :).. Thanks a lot, thank you very much :)..

Answer (score 1):

My suggession is create one or two jobs and use dynamic sql to run sp's in loop. you can run a sp available in another database by exec [Database1].[dbo].usp_procedurename @parametr1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `sp_MSforeachdb` will solve your purpose. Pair it with an If Clause to select/ ignore certain databases.

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000)

SELECT @command = 'IF ''?'' IN(''myDB1'', ''myDB2'', ''myDB3'') BEGIN USE ? Select db_Name() END'

--Print @command

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Comment: This solution is elegant. How can we use 'Select db_Name()' command as a separate variable and append it into the @command variable?